# React Production Mode

Tags: reactjs, build, production

I created the build file for my React JS project. As soon the build `index.html` file in browser, everything worked fine, except for a single image that I have provided in my Topbar Component. The image appears broken, even after it is present in my application folder.

Here is the screenshot of broken image:

[image]

and this is how the image element looks in inspect tool:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest the reason for this?

Comment: If you right click on the link and click on `Open in new tab" Does the image opens ?

Comment: Hi  Bubble have you given right path to the image which means the image path should exist with in the public folder then only it will  load and the format is like <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">

Comment: @HamzaBaig No it does not. But the file do exists in my local folder.

Comment: @BhavaniMandapati Yes the path is right. It is properly visible while in development mode

Comment: @BhavaniMandapati File imports are not allowed outside the src folder. Even if tried, it gives error such as: `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../public/settings.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: yes . Previously i had faced this issue. the image will not load outside the public folder. So you declared out side the folder try to place it with in folder and see the result how it could be.

Comment: @BhavaniMandapati I placed the image inside the public folder. Then this error came

Comment: In first Comment I have mention one example also once look at that example in that favicon-32x32.png is the file name which is exist in public folder and one more thing index.html also in public folder right so we just give /and file name of image

Comment: @bubble-cord no need of importing img into public file we can direct access using /filename

Answer (score 0):

We have to Create image file with in the public folder then access the image file in href 
`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img.png">` here img.png is the image file name and see the folder structure is like

- project
- public -- >index.html
- public -- >  img.png
- src
- package.json

Comment: I tried your answer and the official react documentation also. Everything works fine for development mode but not in production. The image still crashes

Comment: @bubble-cord can you post your index.html code then I might be able to find out the issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is how my index.html looks like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xj59gk

Comment: @bubble-cord in your post in index.html page you are using image tag right instead of image try with link tag <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img.png">